# Installing H2o-3 in R

Tags: r, h2o

I use the following code to install h2o-3 in R

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
    if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
    if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

    # Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
    pkgs <- c("methods","statmod","stats","graphics","RCurl","jsonlite","tools","utils")
    for (pkg in pkgs) {
      if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
    }

    # Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
    install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos=(c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/3/R")))
    library(h2o)
    localH2O = h2o.init(nthreads=-1)

    # Finally, let's run a demo to see H2O at work.
    demo(h2o.kmeans)
```

***It shows the following error.***

Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library" C:\Users\pintoo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpUxsC47/downloaded_packages/h2o_3.10.0.3.tar.gz' had status 65535
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status

## Then, as the above code, doesn't install package, and it shows it has been downloaded so i tried installing using the downloaded package using the below code

```
install.packages("C:/Users/pintoo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUL3Da2/downloaded_packages/h2o_3.10.0.3.tar.gz",
                       repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = T)
```

It produced the below error

Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\library" "C:/Users/pintoo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUL3Da2/downloaded_packages/h2o_3.10.0.3.tar.gz"' had status 65535
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/pintoo/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpUL3Da2/downloaded_packages/h2o_3.10.0.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

**MY version :**

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
arch           x86_64
os             mingw32
system         x86_64, mingw32
status
major          3
minor          3.1
year           2016
month          06
day            21
svn rev        70800
language       R
version.string R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
nickname       Bug in Your Hair

> Can any one help me out.
>
> What is this non-zero exit status. 
>   status 65535 meaning?
>   Non- zero exit status of package means?

Comment: Why do you have 2 install.packages commands in your code? Did you follow the full instructions on the h2o website? Because your code is missing a bit.

Comment: Sorry I installed only once. But I am getting the above error.

Comment: I tried both installations seperately , but couldn;t get rectified

Comment: Did you install JDK (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) before installing the R package? See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf --> `SystemRequirements Java (>= 1.7)`

Comment: Make sure it's the 64-bit JDK.  On the page linked above, that would be "Windows x64" instead of "Windows x86".

Answer (score 3):

The error message you gave is for the second of your two install lines; you don't say what happened with the first one.

But, my recommended way to install H2O on R:

```
install.packages("h2o")
```

Simple! This will get the latest version from CRAN, and automatically find all the dependencies. The downside is you are a version or so behind the latest. But the product is mature (so being a version back is fine) *and* development is fairly rapid (so being a version back can sometimes even be better)!

Only use the [instructions on the H2O site](http://www.h2o.ai/download/h2o/r) if you have a good reason to need the latest version. (And I still recommend installing the first time from CRAN, as it is harder to get something wrong, so if *that* doesn't work, maybe H2O is incompatible with your machine or something like that.)

---

P.S. The 65535 (i.e. -1) error code is probably a Windows one, and from some googling appears to be a generic one meaning something crashed. If you do pursue it, I'd be suspicious about either access permissions to certain directories, or paths with spaces in them. (IIRC, R used to recommend not installing in directories with spaces in them.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, please go through the above edited query.  CRAN h2o, is producing error in the key argument in the foll code,         prostate.hex <- h2o.assign(data = prostate.hex, key =
"myNewName"),     **no key argument is found**

Comment: @varun I'm confused: if you are on to using `h2o.assign()`, does that mean running the simple `install.packages("h2o")` worked? If you have successfully installed H2O, and have a question about `h2o.assign()` that should be a new question. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts )